# Excel Cell Link to InfoPath sending data to SharePoint

Tags: excel

I want to be able to send out an Excel file with a list of clients and use that file to be able to open up a form when they click on a client.

The form would be pre-populated with information from the Excel file and have additional fields the associate would update.  The compelted form would be send to a SharePoint site which would consolidate the information.

Does this sound possible?

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath forms can use URL input parameters - you can add a parameter to the link in the Excel file like "clientid=123" and then add code to your InfoPath form to handle for passed in parameters.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.loadingeventargs.inputparameters.aspx) is a link to the MSDN page on the code needed - `LoadingEventArgs.InputParameters` property

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/02/26/passing-data-into-a-form-input-parameters.aspx) is a link to the former InfoPath team blog that has more details on how to leverage input parameters.

The InfoPath form could then use a SharePoint Library submit data connection to submit to a library.